# HTML5 shiv breaks page in ie8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I am a beginner at html5.  When I try to call the html5 shiv the page wont render in ie8. Only the background loads.

I am adding the following

```
<header>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">     </script><![endif]-->   
<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('hgroup');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
```

css:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {     display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't have to create all the elements with `document.createElement` - shiv does it for you.
2. In your CSS you make all the new elements `inline` for IE8, however they're naturally block in the good browsers. Try to make them consistent and use the rules from [*Normalize CSS*](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) for example:

```css
    /*
    * Corrects `block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
    */

    article,
    aside,
    details,
    figcaption,
    figure,
    footer,
    header,
    hgroup,
    nav,
    section,
    summary {
        display: block;
    }

    /*
    * Corrects `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
    */

    audio,
    canvas,
    video {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    /*
    * Prevents modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
    * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
    */

    audio:not([controls]) {
        display: none;
        height: 0;
    }
```